# Redirect url inside url

Tags: url, redirect, history, back

I have an external forum login form on my website but after logging in I would like users to redirect back to the **exact website page that the visitor was looking at before logging in.**

The thing I use:

```
<script>
function goBack()
{
window.history.go(-1)
}
</script>

<form action="./forum/ucp.php?mode=login" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label for="username">Name:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="20" class="input"><br>
<label for="password">Password:</label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="20" class="input"><br>
<label for="autologin">Remember<input type="checkbox" name="autologin" id="autologin"></label><br>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="goBack()">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in" class="button">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

However, the browser redirects to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/forum/goBack()?sid=87b53e6ecb0ae9062a3a9b930
```

I only manage to redirect to the index of my website:

```
value="http://www.wow.com">
```

Who will help me out :)?

Comment: Show the code that uses this hidden field.

Comment: You haven't shown the PHP code that uses the `redirect` field. If it's just putting the value in the `Location:` header, that won't work; that header contains a URL, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code :

```
<?php
//perform your post operations
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
?>
<script>
window.history.go(-2); // -1 will post on the page from which it has been posted
</script>
<?php
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="fname">
    Email <input type="text" name="email" id="emailid">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```